# New line for text from cursor

Tags: android

In my application I receive a text from a database file using a cursor. I would like the text to have "new line" characters. The problem is that the text is displayed with the new line character in it. For example: "First line \n Second line" is displayed instead of "First line" on a line and "Second line" on the next line. If I set the same text manually to the text view everything looks ok. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case this characters set `&#xA;` should be for newline.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your TextView in layout.xml

`android:singleLine="false" android:maxLines="2"`

Comment: It's not about having 2 lines. It's about breaking the current line whenever the new line character (\n) is encountered. It works if I set the text to the text view, but it doesn't if I receive the text from a database.

Comment: Can you explain me how to do that, please?